# MVC knockout Cascading dropdown from arrays

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

New to Knockout, migrating my MVC application from using Telerik MVC combobox to Knockout.
I generate two arrays using Ajax, and bind them to Knockout select using the following:

```
<select data-bind='options: myFirstList, optionsText: "Text", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: 0'> </select>
<select data-bind='options: mySecondList, optionsText: "Text", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: 0'> </select>



  function myViewModel() {
        this.myFirstList = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.mySecondList = ko.observableArray([]);

       }
    var objVM = new myViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(objVM);

Using Ajax:
  $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/CheckWord',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                cword: wordtocheck
            },
            success: function (data) {
              .....

                }
                objVM.mySecondList(stateList[0]);

                var fnArray = [];

                for (var k = 0; k < data.fnList.length; ++k) {
                    fnArray[k] = { Text: data.fnList[k], Value: k };
            }

                objVM.myFirstList(fnArray);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("n");
            }
        });
```

Could not figure out how to change the second select list based on the item selected from the first list, and how to trigger Javascript action with an item is selected from the second list.
Would appreciate if someone can point me to an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in HTML, bind 'value' to observable**

```
<select data-bind='options: myFirstList, optionsText: "Text",
  optionsCaption: "Select...", value: myFirstListSelected'> </select>
<select data-bind='options: mySecondList, optionsText: "Text",
  optionsCaption: "Select...", value: mySecondListSelected'> </select>
```

**in JS, use subscribe to listen to change event of the model**

```
function myViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.myFirstList = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.mySecondList = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.myFirstListSelected = ko.observable();
  self.mySecondListSelected = ko.observable();
  // when first selected changes
  self.myFirstListSelected.subscribe(function(newVal) {
    // ignore blank selection
    // or you can clear second list when user deselects first one.
    // if (newVal == null) {
    //   self.mySecondListSelected(undefined);
    //   self.mySecondList.removeAll();
    //   return;
    //  }
    if (newVal == null) return;
    $.ajax({
      //...
      data: { cword: newVal },
      success: function (data) {
        //...
        // clear selected
        self.mySecondListSelected(undefined);
        // reload second list
        self.mySecondList(stateList[0]);
        //...
      }
      //...
    });
  });
  // when second selected changes
  self.mySecondListSelected.subscribe(function(newVal) {
    //... beware newVal could be null or undefined when user deselects it.
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to pass the value from myFirstList of the selected item, for example 2 for second item to mySecondList  objVM.mySecondList(stateList[2]), to update it.  I could not Ajax with newVal.  Also how can I get the value of selected item from the second list.

Comment: sorry, did not check your code. objVM is not visible, use `self` in the callback. Updated answer.

Comment: Inside the callback, `newVal` is current value. If you want to access the value in other place, just call `self.myFirstListSelected()`.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. Your myFirstList holds [1,2,3...], not words to pass to the ajax call, right? If this is the case, modify the code in ajax, `data: {cword: wordtocheck}` `self.mySecondList(stateList[newVal]);`

Comment: If the above is true, then only need to fire ajax once, holds all result somewhere, and use `self.myFirstListSelected.subscribe(function(newVal) { self.mySecondListSelected(undefined); self.mySecondList(savedStateList[myVal]);});`

Comment: Thank you, how can I get myVal when I call alert(newVal) inside self.myFirstListSelected.subscribe, I get object object.  Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: Thank you again, I used    (myVal = newVal.Value); works great.